# How to output R square and RMSE in SAS

Tags: sas

I regress Y on X. The regression is grouped by DATE.

```
proc reg data=A noprint;
    model Y=X;
    by DATE;
run;
```

In the regression result for each DATE, there is a R square and a RMSE value.
How do I output a table of R square and RMSE values as below. Thank you!

```
|------------|-----------|------------|
|    Date    |  R Square |    RMSE    |
|------------|-----------|------------|
|  1/1/2009  |     R1    |    RMSE1   |
|  2/1/2009  |     R2    |    RMSE2   |
|  3/1/2009  |     R3    |    RMSE3   |
|    ....    |    ....   |    ....    |
|  10/1/2010 |     R22   |    RMSE22  |
|  11/1/2010 |     R23   |    RMSE23  |
|  12/1/2010 |     R24   |    RMSE24  |
|------------|-----------|------------|
```

Comment: Do you want it as printed output, or as a dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at one of the examples of the SAS PROC REG, this is pretty easy to do.

The example data:

```
data htwt;
      input sex $ age :3.1 height weight @@;
      datalines;
   f 143 56.3  85.0 f 155 62.3 105.0 f 153 63.3 108.0 f 161 59.0  92.0
   f 191 62.5 112.5 f 171 62.5 112.0 f 185 59.0 104.0 f 142 56.5  69.0
   f 160 62.0  94.5 f 140 53.8  68.5 f 139 61.5 104.0 f 178 61.5 103.5
   f 157 64.5 123.5 f 149 58.3  93.0 f 143 51.3  50.5 f 145 58.8  89.0
   m 164 66.5 112.0 m 189 65.0 114.0 m 164 61.5 140.0 m 167 62.0 107.5
   m 151 59.3  87.0
   ;
run;
```

Now, the PROC REG.  Pay particular attention to the OUTEST statement; this is going to output a dataset `est1` that will contain what you want.

```
proc reg outest=est1 outsscp=sscp1 rsquare;
      by sex;
      eq1: model  weight=height;
      eq2: model  weight=height age;

   proc print data=sscp1;
      title2 'SSCP type data set';

   proc print data=est1;
      title2 'EST type data set';
   run;
quit;
```

So now, the last PROC PRINT of est1 can be easily routed to contain only what you want:

```
proc print data=est1;
var sex _RMSE_ _RSQ_;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
proc reg data=A noprint;
model Y=X;
by DATE;
ods output FitStatistics=final_table;
run;
data final_table; set final_table;
    rename cValue1=RMSE;
    rename cValue2=RSquared;
proc print data=final_table;
    where Label1='Root MSE';
    var DATE RSquared RMSE;
run;
```

I simply turned the trace on and took the name of the table I was interested in and saved it as the output of proc reg.

```
ODS Trace on;
proc reg data=A noprint;
model Y=X;
by DATE;
run;
ODS Trace off;
```

this prints out the name of all the output tables in the log file.

Comment: Thank you Sara! But when I run this, there are warnings shown.

WARNING: Output 'FitStatistics' was not created.

WARNING: The variable cValue1 in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.

WARNING: The variable cValue2 in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.

Do you know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: it maybe that these tables and variables have different names in your SAS. I'm using SAS Enterprise 9.3. Anyways, I think the best is to take noprint out of your proc reg statement and turn the trace on. add ODS TRACE ON; before proc reg and run it. In the log file it prints out the name of each table that is shown in the output. take the name of the table that has R-squared and RMSE values and replace that with Fitstatistics in my code. From there you can see what is the name of the variables of you interest in the output table, and then use a keep or drop to clear out your table.